# Postname permalink page not found error

Tags: theme-development

Page not found error when using permalink ‘postname’setting.Some pages are working for example http://example.com/questions is working but pages like http://example.com/questions/something.   This is the case with my custom theme.Twenty twelve is working fine.Any suggesion?Default permalink setting also works fine.

Comment: Please provide more details about your custom theme. Are you trying to access a custom post type? Page? Post? Is "something" a child of "questions" or is it "questions" a custom post type, and "something" the post?

Comment: In this link 'http://example.com/questions' questions is a custom post type named 'questions'.I am using DW question & answer plugin.The hyperlink Upto that first slash is working.The second link is a link to a particular question like  http://example.com/question/how to prevent kidneystone & the word 'question' is actually a custom permalink provided by that plugin.

Comment: If the custom post type is provided by the plugin you are using, your best bet to get support would be from the plugin's author [here](https://wordpress.org/support/plugin/dw-question-answer).

Answer (score 0):

This is likely related to a problem with the plugin itself, or a conflict with another plugin.

The other thing to check would be that your .htaccess file exists and is writable by WordPress. Permissions of 644 are what is recommended [see this codex entry](http://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_File_Permissions#.htaccess_permissions).

Ownership of the .htaccess file would generally need to be the apache user (sometimes this is `www`, on CPanel its usually `nobody`, but that will vary by web host or Operating System). If you're running on Windows, that is [another story](http://48web.com/wordpress-iis-permissions-updates-permalinks/).

There is another decent article about .htaccess permissions [here](http://www.elegantthemes.com/blog/tips-tricks/wordpress-htaccess-tips-and-tricks).

For posterity, here is how to change permissions and ownership of the htaccess file:

```
chmod 644 .htaccess
chown apacheuser:apacheuser .htaccess
```

You can usually find out permissions and ownership in your website's root by using this command:

```
ls -l
```

Remember to be careful when changing ownership and permissions and consult with your hosting company if you are at all unsure of what you're doing.

Comment: No i checked everything related to htaccess the problem is with my custom theme only.Something is missing in my theme.Other themes are working fine.How to add support for custom post display in custom theme

Comment: Nothing is missing from your theme, your theme is doing something wrong if its preventing a custom post type from working.

Comment: i have used another plugin anspress that is having custom post type but it is working fine. i have nothing more to say.

Comment: then you should ask the people who made the plugin that doesn't work, as was suggested yesterday.

Comment: some plugin authors gave vague ideas.So i asked here.Some people have faced similar problems in the past.They can help me.

Comment: My problem got solved.There is some problem in the functions.php I changed it

Comment: Consider posting your resolution with code examples here as an answer for other people who come after you who might have a similar issue. Enjoy!